# How to secure azure website and data deployment

Tags: azure, ssl-certificate, x509certificate

I'm working on large scale web application with lots of customer data. It's a CMS system, where the content authoring resided on-premise and delivery website hosted in azure.

From time to time we need to perform deployment of new changes and also publish of content from on premise cMS to azure.

I understand that we can use either Publish Setting or self-signed Certificate for authentication. But what I don't know is:

1. Which option (Azure Publish Setting or Self Signed Cert) is more secure to avoid MiTM attack?
2. Do we need to buy third party CA signed Certificate and if so what type (as it's not for website but for azure X509 authentication)?

Thank you heaps.

Answer (score 2):

Simply use https instead of http when you are publishing data to protect it from tampering and eavesdropping during transmission.

A self signed certificate will suffice. You do not need to buy a trusted CA certificate for this purpose since you control both ends of transmission and can pre-configure that your self-signed certificate is trusted.

You only need a CA certificate when you expect random clients to trust your certificate, like when you expose your own https endpoint.

You may wish to have a look at [Azure Vitual Network](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windowsazure/jj156007.aspx) for alternative approaches.